# Does creating developer account on Windows Dev Centre during Targeted App Distribution provides with Enterprise Sideload key?

Tags: windows

We have implemented a Windows 8 app. We tested the app by sideloading on both Windows 8.1 Pro and Enterprise. The app is working as expected when both the machines are connected to the domain. If both the machines are out of the domain, the app does not work and we receive the following error ‘This app can’t open. There’s a problem with app. Contact your system administrator about repairing or reinstalling it’. Also, in the event log the following error was displayed ‘Activation of the app 589f3680-7094-4066-92ee-75cd86b75bc1_5gyrq6psz227t!App for the Windows. Launch contract was blocked with error 0x80073CFC because its package is in state: Modified‘. We checked through on your sites and it is mentioned that Enterprise Sideloading key is mandatory for the app to work if the machine is not connected to the domain.
If we publish the app on Windows Store using ‘Targeted App Distribution’ method, do we still need to worry about the Enterprise Sideloading key or will the key be available when we will create a developer account on the Windows Center?  Let us know.
 Let us know if we are missing anything. Also, it will be helpful if you suggest any appropriate way as we need the Windows app to work without being connected to the domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could sideload the app if you have a developer license registered on the target machine. You can get a developer license via Visual Studio or with this powershell command:

```
Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense
```

However the developer license needs to be renewed every month.

See my answer here how to sideload an app: 
[sideload windows 8 apps to multiple devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524265/sideload-windows-8-apps-to-multiple-devices/31005993#31005993)